# Why can't I ignore a return value of a call using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When I call this from an external type in Powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "$sdk_path\bin\DataProvider.dll"
$queryProcessor = New-Object -Type QuestionAnswering.QueryProcessor($linguisticDB, $index)
$queryProcessor.Process(query)
```

I can see that the function call returns an int. I get the following error message:

```
The result type 'System.Int32' of the dynamic binding produced by the object with type 
'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' for the binder 'PSInvokeMember: Process ver:0 
args:1 constraints:<args: >' 
is not compatible with the result type 'System.Object' expected by the call site.
```

I don't need the int value for anything, but I can't seem to instruct Powershell to ignore it. For example, these still return the same error:

```
[void]$queryProcessor.Process(query)
$queryProcessor.Process(query) | Out-Null
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are hitting a bug in PowerShell.

Try the following as a workaround:

```
$queryProcessor.Process.Invoke(query)
```

Comment: Perfect, that works!

I don't pretend to understand the difference though :-/

Comment: I can think of only a handful of people that would have even thought of trying this as a workaround, so no worries about understanding it.

Comment: And to explain - $queryProcessor.Process returns a PSMethod.  The code path that implements PSMethod.Invoke(...) doesn't have the bug.

Comment: If this repros in V4, can you open a bug (http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell) with sufficient repo details.  I tried to repro w/ V4 but I couldn't guess what conditions trigger this bug.